# Could Data layer contain objects and logic from android framework packages

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio

I'm trying to make an app with Clean Architecture. I want to press button from my activity and start scheduler to check if week have passed.

So I have AlarmScheduler interface (which i want to pass in Domain layer) that contain only one function

```
interface AlarmScheduler {
    fun schedule(someString: String)
}
```

And also I have implementation (which I want to pass in Data layer) AndroidAlarmSchedulerImpl
Code looks like this:

```
class AndroidAlarmScheduler(
    private val context: Context,
): AlarmScheduler {

    private val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(AlarmManager::class.java)

    @SuppressLint("ScheduleExactAlarm")
    override fun schedule(someString: String) {
        val intent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java).apply {
            this.putExtra(ALARM_INTENT_STRING_EXTRA, someString)
        }

        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY)
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)

        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar.timeInMillis,
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                0,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )
        )
    }
}
```

The problem is could I pass android framework logic outside presentation layer? If you know any solutions please describe it.

Comment: Well, you are not passing "Android framework package". You pass an abstraction of "AlarmScheduler". This is the way - I mean, can you see any ".android" package reference in the (presumably) use case?

Comment: @TheLibrarian, Maybe I understood your anwer wrong but if you talk about AlarmScheduler then it's in Domain layer but I'm asking about AndroidAlarmScheduler which have android logic (like Intent). Cuz it's seems wrong to place it inside Data layer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to give a good answer to my question and as I managed to understand you are free to do whatever you want. But I found a good example of how you can manage your project structure and also this project contain an example where you can pass your Alarm manager logic in project.
Here is a link: https://github.com/tolgaprm/Mova-MovieApp/tree/main.
Enjoy!
If somebody will give better answer I will change the answer of question.